# Book involving spaceships with engines that used crystals and a pirate space navy

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, pirates

I'm trying to find a book I read in the early 80's or maybe the late 70's.

It had spaceships with engines that used crystals. There was a pirate space navy. They had some kind of tattoos on their necks that only showed up in certain situations. Their main base was under a big nebula that looked like I think it was a wave about to crash down on them. The ship's captain was formerly one of the pirates. The mechanic was from a rich family, but didn't want people to know. I think the main character was a teenager, I want to say a girl.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possibly Samuel R. Delany's *Babel-17*, though it has been so long since I read it that I can't be sure. It has space pirates and mobile 'living' tattoos that can fade into the skin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel-17